# Backbone.js with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm currently trying Backbone.js along with a rails app. My problem is, that I don't know how to implement the Backbone controllers and views with my rails app. I've read a lot of tutorials, but they are always using just one controller in backbone.js.

For example, I have two controllers in rails.

- Activities Controller

  - Includes two views, a google map and a search field. The google map is inserted with a backbone view, the searchfield is in HTML and gets its functionality through a backbone view.
  - The search field should fetch data from my rails model and display markers inside the map.

And the other one is

- Users Controller

  - Here the users profile is viewed, and I want to add some ajax functionality like updating values and other things

In my application.js I start the app using

```
var App = {
  Views: {},
  Controllers: {},
  Collections: {},
  init: function() {
      new App.Controllers.Activities();
      new App.Controllers.Users();
      Backbone.history.start();
  }
};

$(function() {
  App.init();
});
```

The problem is, that I don't need the Activities controller in my User Profile and the Users controller in the Rails Activities controller. How could I solve this? Should I try reading the current URL within javascript and then decide which controller is used?
Or should I put the JavaScript file into the application.html.erb and then decide here which controller should be used?

Or is this the wrong way to use backbone.js controllers?

Am I getting sth wrong with the structure of backbone.js? Or am I using the Controllers in a wrong way?

Another question is, how to add little JavaScript, in particular jQuery, functionality through Backbone.js? For example, I want to remove the label inside a field, when the user clicks into the field. Or I want to do some tab-functionality and just toggle the visibility of some elements.
Should I create for each element that is using javascript a Backbone view? Or is this overload?

Hope I made myself clear and anybody can help,
thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make use of the routes feature Backbone provides to decide which method to call? The activities controller would contain only routes use for activities, the user controller only for the user handling, and so forth.
Like this you can instantiate the controller just as you do and the routing will decide what happens based on the current location's hash.

If you can't use links with hashes (or there are no such links on your page), I'd simply name my view containers specific enough to attach events only for the current view when needed.

jQuery plugins etc. belong into views IMO. Same goes for your tabs and input hint toggle.

**Update**

On a general level (and I would **not** necessarily recommend doing it this way): If you have two methods:

```
// should be only called for the 'Foo' controller
function foo() {
  alert("FOO");
};

// should be only called for the 'Bar' controller
function bar() {
  alert("BAR");
};
```

and want to call only one of them depending on the current Rails controller, create a small helper:

e.g. in you *helpers/application_helper.rb*

```
def body_class
  controller.controller_name
end
```

then call this method in your layout file (or header partial):

```
<body class="<%= body_class %>">
…
```

and use e.g. jQuery to "split" your JS execution:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('foo')) {
  foo();
} else if ($('body').hasClass('bar')) {
  bar();
}
```

Comment: Using the routes is a good idea! But as you said my url's dont have a hash in it. I'm using the standard rails routes. Is there a better way ti decide which controller to choose? Or maybe I'll fork backbone.js and add this functionality. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think a fork is necessary. Your controllers are only classes, nothing should really happen unless you call one of these classes' methods. Could you explain what you're doing within your controllers that makes you want to "split" the code this way? (On a more general level: I'll add another way to invoke JS depending on the current Rails controller to my answer.)

Comment: thx for you comment and your update. But I don't like this method that CSS is involved on deciding which controller should be used. I want to split this code in this way, because I think it's clearer to keep the JavaScript code of the activities controller apart from other controllers. For example, I have a map in the activities controller and in the users controller. The view is the same, but the behaviour is different. Another thing is, how could I handle this within particular rails method (lets say, code only belongs to a method of a controller, e.g. the new action)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow you completely, but if the behaviour is different then the view can't be the same IMO. Since the behaviour is view behaviour it belongs into the view. I think I you might have to let go of the idea that a Backbone Controller == Rails Controller. I don't think you can apply the same logic to both environments.

Comment: Backbone.Collection = Rails controller (in a restful way). Backbone controllers are there to control the flow on the client side. One backbone controller can actually act upon many different rails controllers based on the data loaded. I think in your case you do not want to build single page app, but have backbone handle dynamic behvior within a page.

Comment: Julien basically restated what my answer says: if you dont need a single page app(which you dont given your question), you dont need to use Backbone Controller, but do use other parts of Backbone such as Collections, Models and Views to structure your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use jammit (from the same author of backbone). You can group stylesheets and javascripts files by module and use them on your different pages. So you create a module for your activities view and another for your user view each requiring the necessary JavaScript file. Two nice things about this:

- you have only code used on the page loaded on the page
- jammit comprsses everything for you

This is the way to go when not creating a single page web app where you relies on # routes to navigate from one controller to another. In your case you have multiple single page apps inside a main rails app.

Comment: Jammit could be a good way to do this. But I'm wondering if there could be a performance problem. Because you compress javascript files for each controller into one single file, you create a unique file for each controller (or even for each action). So everytime you access a new page, the whole Backbone.js and (in my case) jQuery framework gets loaded, because it's included in a single file. How could I handle this? Keeping Backbone.js and jQuery apart from Jammit? But then I can't benefit from the fact, that I only have one JS file and a smaller number of HTTP request. What do you think?

Comment: I have a common.js file with jQuery & backbone and one js file for a set of rails views. That would be 2 requests and once the common.js file is loaded (and cached), 1 request. Jammit will compress files to an assets folder that it will use for production deployment. No compression in this environment.

Comment: Note that in Rails 3.1, the asset pipeline feature does what Jammit does (for JS, CSS), allowing the nice separation of functionality across files.  For a smaller app, the default behavior is better -- all JS gets minified/de-commented/etc into a single file, which then is cached locally on the browser.  Very apps can use the manifest options to determine how the files are packaged and when they are sent.

Comment: Sorry, missed my 5-minute comment edit deadline...  I don't think the concern @23tux raises in the first comment (performance) is likely to be an issue except for very large apps, assuming browser caching is done properly (a compressed JS file is sent once only).  Rails 3.1 handles all of this transparently :-)

Answer (score 1):

Im a Backbone.js newb, so please someone correct me if Im wrong, but I think youre confusing what Backbone controllers are used for.

Backbone.js controllers basically consists of hashbang routes(similar to Rails routes) and actions that these routes call. For instance if you have a rails route that will render a view at http://mysite.com/backbone_test and you have a following backbone route:

```
var MyController = Backbone.Controller.extend({
  routes: {
    "foo/:bar":            "myFirstFunction"
  },
  myFirstFunction: function(bar){
    console.log(bar);
  });
```

then if you go to http://mysite.com/backbone_test#foo/THIS-IS-AMAZING then MyController.MyFirstFunction gets executed and "THIS-IS-AMAZING" gets logged in JS console.

Unless you have a direct need for this sort of hashbang-related functionality, such as saving a state of your JavaScript application via an url (for example: http://my.app.com/#key=value&key=value&ad-infinitum=true ) Id advise against using Backbone controllers. You can get all of the functionality u described via Models Collections and Views.

Nice thing about Controllers and Backbone in general is that its modular and different parts can be used independently.

I guess the summary of this answer is that if you dont have a single page javascript application, do not use Backbone Controllers, rely on your rails controllers instead.

Comment: thx for your comment, but I think even if you don't have a single page javascript app you can (or should) use Backbone.js when the JavaScript part gets bigger. I want to be able to use the RESTful way Backbone.js is communicating with my controllers.

Comment: I didnt say you shouldnt use Backbone.js. In fact, I love Backbone.js because it forces you to structure your Javascript code and avoid spaghetti code trap.                                             What i did say is that you dont always need to use Backbone.js Controller especially if you dont need hashtagged routes in your application.

Comment: Uh, I'm sorry, I misread your answer. But I came to the point, that I don't need the controllers and lots of the other stuff backbone provides. Now I'm using require.js for my modules. Thx for your answer! It's a really really great community here!

Comment: No problem. Im still a Backbone and JS newb, but I am actually using Backbone more and more to structure my code and to easily bind models and views through event triggers. Like I said, Backbone is useful regardless of controllers. In fact, I think Controllers were only "recently" added to Backbone